# Script Shell: Display date of two minutes (period)

Tags: shell, script

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
while :; do
   sleep 1
   date
done
```

How can I change this script display the time only of two minutes (period) and exit?

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use a counter and only do 2 iterations.

```
ctr=1
while [ ${ctr} -le 2 ]; do 
  sleep 1
  date
  ((ctr++))
done
```

Note that "sleep 1" will only sleep for 1 second. If you want 2 'minutes' to be displayed you should increase sleep to "sleep 60" so each iteration is paused for a full minute and the date command will then show a difference of 2 minutes and not 2 seconds.

Comment: Thank you for answer. i need to display time each second for two minutes (period) only. So i have to use  while [ ${ctr} -le 120 ]    that's it ?

Comment: That should work yes